# How to use the items of the list, with the glob.glob to get the files?

Tags: python, pandas, glob

There are various csv files in the directory containing dates as name(`somename_20210202.csv`, `xyzname_20210305.csv`, etc.). I would like to read the files for the given date range mentioned below. With the list of those dates, I created a pattern of files. Further, I want to use that pattern in glob.glob to get files but `globbed_files` returning empty list. My code is correct till `pattern_list`. Please suggest where is the problem.

```
from datetime import timedelta, date
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import glob
import os
import datetime as dt

def daterange(date1, date2):
    for n in range(int ((date2 - date1).days)+1):
        yield date1 + timedelta(n)

 start_dt = date(2020,01,15)
 end_dt = date(2020,02,10)

abc = []
weekdays = [5,6]
for dt in daterange(start_dt, end_dt):
    if dt.weekday() not in weekdays:
        abc.append(dt.strftime("%d-%b-%Y"))
        #print(dt.strftime("%d-%b-%Y"))
print(abc)

dir = r"C:\User\Folder"
pattern_list = []
for dates in abc:
    pattern = f'*_{dates}.csv' # use wildcards (*)
    pattern_list.append(pattern)
print(pattern_list)

for x in pattern_list:
    globbed_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(dir, x))
    print(globbed_files)
```

Comment: Your dates are formatted `%d-%b-%Y` in `abc`, but your example file name has a different pattern, i.e. `20210202`. Are those example file names correct? If so, change your `df.strftime(%d-%b-%Y)` to match that pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Your pattern is correct and also get files from the glob module is correct. Only make sure your **. csv** file exists in your file directory(`'C:\User\Folder'`) path and then you will get the same result from `globbed_files` otherwise bank list.

For example:

Creates two or more file as  `a_20210202.csv, b_20210202.csv and c_20210305.csv` etc...

and set your pattern date list as well like:

```
pattern_list = [*_20210202.csv, *_20210305.csv]
```

then:

```
dir = "your created files folder path"
for x in pattern_list:
    globbed_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(dir, x))
    print(globbed_files)
```

**Note**: example only demo purpose only, its static way to creates file and then get.